# Correlation function and power spectrum of discrete time Gaussian noise summed with a time delayed version of itself

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a process $\zeta(n) = \xi(n) + \xi(n + 1)$ Where $\xi(n)$ is discrete time white noise process, where the values taken at different times are from identically distributed Gaussian distribution with standard deviation $\sigma$, i.e. $$\xi(n) = \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) \, .$$
How do we calculate the correlation function $\langle \zeta(n)\zeta(n + m)\rangle$, and power spectrum of this process?

I know the autocorrelation of $\xi$ is
$$\langle \xi(n) \xi(n+m) \rangle = \sigma^2 δ_{m,0}.$$

Comment: I modified the notation to reflect the fact that this is supposed to be a discrete time process.

Comment: hint: expand $\zeta(n)\zeta(n+m) = (\xi(n) + \xi(n + 1))(\xi(n+m) + \xi(n + 1+m))$ and take averages.

Comment: Apiastos, it would be very nice to take the comment by @hyportnex and write your own answer to your own question :-) This is an encouraged practice on Physics Stack Exchange.